# How to make the HTML renders before the alert is triggered?

Tags: javascript, html

The question is actually quite simple. How do I make the div's content change before the alert shows up?

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n2n5drL2/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
Some Text
</div>
<button id="change">
change
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#change').click(function(){
  $('#test').text('new content');
  alert('how to make this alert shows after the div changes its content?')
})
```

Comment: you can put your alert box outside the `Click` function !

Comment: may be helpful : https://jsfiddle.net/n2n5drL2/13/

Comment: You can uncheck the answer yourself - just click the green tick again, or click a different answer if you wish to accept that one instead.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks very much. I should have known this just now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to defer execution of the blocking `alert` so the browser can re-render the changed DOM.  You can do this [with `setTimeout` and a 0ms timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful):

```
$('#change').click(function(){
  $('#test').text('new content');
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('how to make this alert shows after the div changes its content?')
  },0);
})
```

---

It is worth noting, however, that [the specification for `alert`](http://w3c.github.io/html/webappapis.html#dom-window-alert) says to only

> Optionally, pause while waiting for the user to acknowledge the message.

So while I've personally never seen a user-agent treat it as non-blocking, the specification does allow for it.

Answer (score 1):

Delay the `alert` by using a `setTimeout` so that the page has time to re-draw.
When you use `alert` all script execution is halted on the page (eg: the page is basically frozen). But when you call `$.text()` the actual painted data of the text won't be updated until the next `paint` call done by the browser.

Actually, by using `text` you also trigger the `layout` phase of re-rendering the page. So, what happens in this case is you update the text value of that DOM node and the browsers will try to update the graphically displayed data when it is "free", but because you trigger an alert immediately the browser won't be free until you close that alert. By using the `setTimeout` you make sure that the browser is "free" before showing the alert so the text data can be updated.

Read this to understand more about how browsers render the page: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/n2n5drL2/3/

```
$('#change').click(function(){
    $('#test').text('new content');
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('how to make this alert shows after the div changes its content?');
   }, 0);
})
```

Comment: oh, that's the first time I see the usage of `setTimeout(function(){},0)`. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You need to wait at least 1 ms after you change the content:

```
$('#change').click(function(){
    $('#test').text('new content');
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('how to make this alert shows after the div changes its content?');
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: Can I get an explanation for the downvite please?

Answer (score -3):

It should by default, but if not, then set a timeout using `settimeout`

```js
$('#change').click(function() {
  $('#test').text('new content');
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('how to make this alert shows after the div changes its content?')
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  Some Text
</div>
<button id="change">
  change
</button>
```