# In Chrome alert doesn't show HTML until pop up is executed

Tags: javascript, alert

I just started to learn JavaScript and I have a problem with alert. In Chrome alert doesn't show HTML until pop-up is executed.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JavaScript in HTML</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
alert("Helo!");
```

Comment: That is what happens when you use something that blocks the rendering of the page. You can call it onload to make sure the content is loaded fully.

Comment: @epascarello But the script is after the rest of the HTML; It's should execute after the HTML loaded.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman does not mean that the browser drew the page yet....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the HTML renders before the alert is triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086680/how-to-make-the-html-renders-before-the-alert-is-triggered)

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel There jQuery is used.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Your right in thinking that html is written before the javascript but the order of operations in loading browsers is a bit different then whats written top -> bottom. The browser will look at the html file and prepare to render it. Before it renders it though it will run the javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Add an event listener to the [**window**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object and call `alert` within the event handler, when the [**`load`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event occurs:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  alert('Helo!');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript in HTML</h1>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      alert('Helo!');
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or add an event listener to the [**document**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) and use [**`setTimeout`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) with a `0` delay to defer the execution of `alert` within the [**`DOMContentLoaded`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event handler:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Helo!');
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript in HTML</h1>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Helo!');
      }, 0);      
    });    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

With reference to @epascarello's comment, you need to add alert on load of an element or window.
Something like this.
`window.onload = function() {alert('hello');};`

Answer (score 2):

This alert is blocking the load of the html. Use lifecycles to call the javascript after the html is loaded.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    alert("hello")
};
</script>
```

What this code does is checks to see if the browser window is loaded. When this happens you run a function that contains your script.