# Javascript runs before HTML even if at end of body

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript is running before my HTML loads, even if I put it right before the  like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <script>
        alert("yo");
    </script>
</body>
```

Any ideas why that may be happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts)

Comment: yes, it's happening because Javascript is typically executed before anything else on the page, that's just the way it works. If you want to display the html first, you have to set a timer for like x seconds after, or do it on button click. I can help you if you need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the HTML renders before the alert is triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086680/how-to-make-the-html-renders-before-the-alert-is-triggered)

Comment: You should use `DOMContentLoaded` event to prevent that

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas why that may be happening?

`alert` is blocking, script evaluation comes before DomContentLoaded (DCL) and subsequent first content paint (FCP) which is why it doesn't show Title before alert starts blocking the dom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could run it this way:

```
<body onload="alert('yo')">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</body>
```

Or this way:

```
<body onload="my_function()">
<h1>Title</h1>
<script>
    function my_function() {
        alert('yo');
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Inline scripting isn't ideal. Also, this was obviously a duplicate.

Comment: @isherwood I think inline scripting is fine if used properly. Causality is always clear. And I think above example illustrates some basic concepts in a simple way easy to understand.